# Doesn't asking for publish_actions permissions

Tags: javascript, facebook, permissions

So I have a facebook web app that I am building, and in this web I want that people that loging in will accept that the app will post on thier wall.

So on the Login button in the scope section I added the permssion 'publish_actions'.

But when I logging in threw the web facebook doesnt asking for this permission!

Thank you for all the helpers... :D

Comment: Please show the relevant code, we cannot help without seeing how you are trying to do the login/request flow.

Comment: You should never ask for write permissions when the user logs in. Ask for it when you need it